# Error: Facebook Graph API v2.8 Depreciated

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am getting the following error when making calls to Facebook Graph API V2.8:

(OAuthException - #2635) (#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v2.9.

According to FAcebook docs v2.8 should be available until April 2019. Sample call:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{campaignId}/adsets/?fields=id,budget_remaining,campaign_id,configured_status,billing_event,created_time,daily_budget,effective_status,end_time,is_autobid,is_average_price_pacing,lifetime_budget,name,bid_amount,promoted_object,start_time,status,pacing_type,targeting&limit=1000

I would appreciate if any folks using version 2.8 report if they have received these errors.

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#versions, Marketing API v2.8 was available until July 26, 2017 ...

Comment: My fault. I was looking at the API (not including Marketing API) which states "April 18th, 2019".

Either way I am refactoring my code for v2.10. Maybe Facebook should consider making fewer breaking changes to make our life easier.